# Hide Google AdSense error from the browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, adsense

I've an AdSense error showing in my browser logs. This is badly affect my SEO as below

[image]

The ads are shwoing and I'm not blocked by AdSense, this issue from Google part and they don't fix it ( i don't know why)

Anyway, my issue is having these error logs are affecting my SEO becuase it shows error in the browser, and I want in some way to hide the errors and not shwoing. I do have a try catch and left the catch open but this doesn't work.

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
const AdSense = (props) => {
  const { adSlot } = props;  
  useEffect(() => {
      try {
          (window.adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
      }
      catch (e) {
      }
  },[]);
  return (
      <>
          <ins className="adsbygoogle"
              style={{ display: "block", height: '280px' }}
              data-ad-client="{my_id_here}"
              data-ad-slot={adSlot}
              data-ad-format="auto"
              data-full-width-responsive="true">
      </>
  );
};
export default AdSense;
```

I want to hide the errors.

Comment: Can you provide more information about the error? I see you are getting 403 response. What url returns 403? You should be able to see it in the network tab in devtools.